# Ignore one host on an ansible task in a playbook

Tags: ansible

Is there a way to ignore one specific host, in the host group I've specified in my playbook, on only one of the tasks?

```yaml
  - name: Copy master authorized_keys
    copy:
      src: ./configs/authorized_keys
      dest: /home//.ssh/authorized_keys
      force: yes
```

This part of my Ansible playbook copies authorized_keys to my servers, but there's one specific server that has a non-standard authorized_keys.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow; in what way that host is not standard? for that host you need to use a different `authorized_keys` file as source? or is it that it requires to be set in a different destination? this [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may be helpful for the information to include in your questions, (tl dr: `help us to help you`)

Comment: Also, the title indicates that you want to skip one host, is that the case? or do you want to have a different behaviour for that specific host?

Answer (score 2):

There are more options. For example, given the inventory

```bash
shell> cat hosts
test_11
test_12
test_13
```

1. Either declare the list of ignored hosts

```yaml
  hosts_deny: [test_12]
```

and skip them in the task

```yaml
    - name: Copy master authorized_keys
      copy:
        src: configs/authorized_keys
        dest: /home/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys
        force: true
      when: inventory_hostname not in hosts_deny
```

2. or create the list of allowed hosts

```yaml
  hosts_allow: [test_11, test_13]
```

and use it in the task

```yaml
    - name: Copy master authorized_keys
      copy:
        src: configs/authorized_keys
        dest: /home/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys
        force: true
      when: inventory_hostname in hosts_allow
```

Make your choice. Whatever is more convenient. You can also use both conditions

```yaml
    - name: Copy master authorized_keys
      copy:
        src: configs/authorized_keys
        dest: /home/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys
        force: true
      when:
        - inventory_hostname in hosts_allow
        - inventory_hostname not in hosts_deny
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    hosts_deny: [test_12]
    hosts_allow: [test_11, test_13]

  tasks:

    - name: Copy master authorized_keys
      copy:
        src: configs/authorized_keys
        dest: /home/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys
        force: true
      when: inventory_hostname not in hosts_deny

    - name: Copy master authorized_keys
      copy:
        src: configs/authorized_keys
        dest: /home/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys
        force: true
      when: inventory_hostname in hosts_allow

    - name: Copy master authorized_keys
      copy:
        src: configs/authorized_keys
        dest: /home/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys
        force: true
      when:
        - inventory_hostname in hosts_allow
        - inventory_hostname not in hosts_deny
```

---

3. A better approach is to create a data structure. For example, create the tree

```bash
shell> tree .
.
├── ansible.cfg
├── configs
│   ├── default
│   │   └── authorized_keys
│   └── test_12
│       └── authorized_keys
├── hosts
└── pb.yml
```

and declare the variables

```yaml
  find_ak:
    - "configs/{{ inventory_hostname }}/authorized_keys"
    - "configs/default/authorized_keys"
  ak_file: "{{ lookup('first_found', find_ak) }}"
```

See below for how *first_found* works

```bash
shell> ansible-doc -t lookup first_found
```

Then, use the file in the module *authorized_key*

```yaml
    - name: Copy master authorized_keys
      authorized_key:
        user: admin
        key: "{{ lookup('file', ak_file) }}"
```

You can use here the *hosts_deny/hosts_allow* conditions as well.

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    find_ak:
      - "configs/{{ inventory_hostname }}/authorized_keys"
      - "configs/default/authorized_keys"
    ak_file: "{{ lookup('first_found', find_ak) }}"

  tasks:

    - name: Copy master authorized_keys
      authorized_key:
        user: admin
        key: "{{ lookup('file', ak_file) }}"
```